# Show that if $P(|X_n|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.} ) =0$ for every $\epsilon>0$ then $X_n\to 0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

So I know that, for example, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.} ) =0$ would imply $X_n\to 0$ almost surely, but I'm not quite sure how to rigorously show this. I think idea is that since $X_n$ will pop above $\epsilon$ infinitely often with probability 0, then for some $N$, if $n>N$ $|X_n|<\epsilon$ infinitely often with full probability. Is this on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition seems right. Consider the complement of the event in question. This says that for every $1/k,$ 
$$P(|X_n| < 1/k \text{ for all but finite many } n) = 1.$$
So for a fixed $k$, $\limsup|X_n| \leq 1/k$  with probability 1.
Since a countable intersection of probability one events also has probability one, $\limsup|X_n| \leq 1/k$ for every $k$ has probability 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the kicker was just realizing the complement of $\lim \sup A_n$ is just $\lim \inf A_n^c$.