# $\sum_n P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ is convergent for every $\epsilon > 0$ then $X_n \to 0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

Prove when for every $\epsilon > 0$ series $\sum_n P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ is convergent then $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

This seems very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934878/show-that-if-px-n-epsilon-text-i-o-0-for-every-epsilon0-then-x), but in this one we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty}  P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = 0$ due to series convergence.

How can we prove this fact?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma