# Sequence converging in probability has always a subsequence converging almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

This is the second part of a proof verification. Both the claim and the proofs are my thoughts therefore I would like to check for errors.

**Claim**: given a sequence of r.v. converging in probability, there exists always a subsequence converging almost surely.

We first prove a lemma:

**Lemma1**: Given a sequence of positive real numbers $p_n\rightarrow0$, there exists a subsequence $p_{n(k),k>1}$ s.t. $p_{n(k)}=O(1/k^2)$.

Proof: Since the sequence goes to zero, for every $k$
there is $n(k)$ s.t. $p_n<1/k^2$ for every $n\ge n(k)$ (take the smallest possible $n(k)$).The subsequence $p_{n(k)}$ is such that $p_{n(k)}\le1/k^2$ for each $k$, which implies $p_{n(k), k\ge 1}=O(1/k^2)$.

Now use this:

**Lemma2**: We are given a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging in probability to $X$. Fix $\epsilon_k=1/k$. If for every $k\ge 1$,  $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_k)=O(1/n^2)$ than $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$.

(should be proven here [Sequence converging in probability and also almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212022/sequence-converging-in-probability-and-also-almost-surely) , at the moment no mistake was found. The claim in the linked post is slightly different, but the proof reported should lead to the statement in the present form)

Proof of claim:

Fix $\epsilon_k=1/k$. Define $p^{(k)}_{n}\equiv P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_k)$. By definition for each $k$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p^{(k)}_{n}=0$.  By Lemma1, after fixing $k=1$ we can extract a subsequence such that (after renominating $n$) $p^{(1)}_{n}=O(1/n^2)$.
Now take $k=2$ and extract from this subsequence an other one such that also (after rinominating) $p^{(2)}_{n}=O(1/n^2)$, and so on. By a diagonal argument
one can extract a subsequence of the original variables such that $p^{(k)}_{n}=P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_k)=O(1/n^2)$ for each $k$. Now apply Lemma2 to this subsequence to show that the found subsequence converges almost surely.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any errors, though isn't varying $\epsilon$ kind of an overkill? It would have been enough to show that for an arbitrary $\epsilon$, $\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\}$ happens finitely many times, which allows you to avoid a diagonal extraction argument.

EDIT: After the discussion in the comments, I stand corrected; you do need to do this diagonal extraction since you need the extracted sequence to work for arbitrary epsilons. No further comments, and good work!

Comment: I did this because at the moment for a given $\epsilon$ I can extract a subsequence such that the event happens finitely many times with prob 1, but I may extract different subsequences for different $\epsilon$s and the event should happen finitely many times simultaneously for each $\epsilon$s. Than I am a bit in trouble because I would not know how to "merge" the subsequences. The diagonal argument is there for this reason.

Comment: Admittedly, it is a bit confusing :) I will check again... but thanks for your answer and check (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the +1; as for your other concern about fixing epsilon, you might benefit from reading this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934878/show-that-if-px-n-epsilon-text-i-o-0-for-every-epsilon0-then-x

Comment: Not sure how this is related... anyway thx for the link the notation is also quite difficult to follow there...

Comment: That answer argues that if $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon i.o. ) = 0$ for an arbitrary epsilon, then $X_n \rightarrow X$ almost surely. That was just to point out that you do not need to vary your epsilon in your proof, and you could have fixed an epsilon.

Comment: I am not sure that this helps. If you fix an epsilon and extract subsequences for a fixed epsilon, as I did in my answer, you have not guarantee on what happens for different epsilons.  In that answer they have as an hypothesis that the relation is valid for all epsilons. I think the diagonal argument, or smth along these lines, is needed. Maybe you have in mind a different way of proceeding than the one I proposed... I am sure that somebody will say that comments are not for extensive discussion. In case we can discuss more in chat :)

Comment: You work with an arbitrary epsilon; it is similar to showing that a sequence of reals converges; we say that $x_n$ converges to $x$, if, for an arbitrary $\epsilon$, $|x_n - x| \leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ for $N$ sufficiently large. Note that we don't have to vary $\epsilon$ in this definition; working with an arbitrary one is enough. (Also generally the comment that says comments are not for extensive discussion is a bot command)

Comment: Sure we do not have to vary epsilon in the definition, but the sequence is fixed there. In the presentat version, at the step reading "By LEMMA, after fixing k=1,.." I extract a subsequence that works for epsilon=1... if I do that step again with k=2 extracting a subsequence from the original one (and not using the diagonal argument), the two subsequences may be totally unrelated.

Comment: I stand corrected! After thinking about it, I think you are right. You probably do need a subsequence that works uniformly for all $\epsilon$. Thanks for the discussion.